# How to target Outlook.com specifically

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I used to use the code: `[owa] .classname{css here};`
If I filled the "css here" with for example display: none; the class would hide for outlook.com only.

But this code doesn't work for me anymore.
Because of this a great piece of my email doesn't show very well.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6):

Try this in your `<style>` tag:

```
[class="x_foo"] {
  css here
}
```

Outlook.com prefixes class names with `x_` but doesn't do it on attribute selectors. So `<div class="foo">` can be targeted with `[class="x_foo"]` and it'll only apply to Outlook.com.

I don't believe the `[owa]` hack works anymore, so it can be safely removed.