# x_ is being prefixed in each classes and ids in custom html mail template while send mail through laravel

Tags: php, laravel, markdown, laravel-blade, email-templates

x_ is being prefixed in each classes and ids as shown in image attached in custom html mail template while send mail through laravel.

Unable to find a proper working solution to it, actually wants to format the given date into local time format with local time zone using javascript and data is being provided in UTC date time format.

when send this mail, it attach x_ in each and every ids and classes which is also might me making issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{{ env('APP_NAME') }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main-text">

            </div>
            <div class="greeting-text">
                <p>Dear {{ $user->name }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="message-text">
                @php
                    $expiry_date = $subscription->end_date->format('d/m/Y');
                @endphp

                <p>
                    We hope this email finds you well.
                    We noticed that your {{ $subscription->plan->name }} ({{ $subscription->id }}) subscription is about
                    to expire
                    on <span class="expiry_date_txt" id="expiry_date_txt">

                    </span> . To ensure uninterrupted service, we encourage you to renew your
                    plan before it expires.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div> <br>

        <div class="regards-text">
            <p>Thanks,</p>
            <p>{{ env('APP_NAME') }}</p>
        </div>


        <div class="footer-container">
            <div class="social-media-icons">
                <a href="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_TWITTERLINK') }}"><img src="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_TWITTERLINK_URL') }}"
                        alt="Twitter" /></a>
                <a href="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_LINKEDLINK') }}"><img src="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_LINKEDLINK_URL') }}"
                        alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
                <a href="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_FACEBOOKLINK') }}"><img src="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_FACEBOOKLINK_URL') }}"
                        alt="Facebook" /></a>
                <a href="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_YOUTUBELINK') }}"><img src="{{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_YOUTUBELINK_URL') }}"
                        alt="Youtube" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-links">
                <a href="" class="">UNSUBSCRIBE</a><span> | </span>
                <a href="{{ env('MAIL_PRIVACY_POLICY_URL') }}" class="">PRIVACY POLICY</a><span> | </span>
                <a href="{{ env('MAIL_VIST_US_URL') }}" class="">VISIT WEB</a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-text">
                <p class="">
                    {{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_TAGLINE') }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="font-size: 10px; width: fit-content; margin: 10px auto">
                Copyright © All Rights Reserved 2019 -
                <span id="copyright">
                    <script>
                        document
                            .getElementById("copyright")
                            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear()));
                        const expiryDateElement = document.getElementById("expiry_date_txt");
                        const expiryDate = new Date();
                        const localDateString = expiryDate.toLocaleString();

                        expiryDateElement.innerText = localDateString;
                    </script>
                </span>
                {{ env('MAIL_ESIGN_FULLNAME') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

unable to find solution anywhere.

Comment: Did you try different mail clients? Different browsers?

Comment: yes I did, its same

Comment: Some searching suggests Outlook.com does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573691/how-to-target-outlook-com-specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67917603/6089612, https://github.com/W3CGHtmail/html-email-spec/issues/1 ... Are you really seeing it in other clients?